# HSQLDB persistence in a Spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, hsqldb

I checked a lot of answers but I didn't understand most of them, so please bear in mind that I'm very new to programming and Java.

So, I was following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@fsonmezay/restful-issue-tracking-application-with-spring-boot-and-angularjs-61b69537b10e

But as noted in that, everything I do on the UI while the app is running disappears when I close the app.

It uses HSQLDB as the database manager, and I need the app to write on the database everything that I add while it is running.

Also, don't know if it's worth mentioning but instead of using maven, I'm using Gradle.

Comment: Expected behaviour, hsqldb is an in-memory database, it is active only while app is up & running. Once your application is down, your data & schema in hsqldb will be completely lost. Know more on in-memory databases. You can create data.sql in resources folder of your project to initialise your dabase with initial data, like some table creations, inserting some data

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring Boot autoconfigures in-memory HSQLDB connection, so all data obviously will be lost. You need to provide `spring.datasource.url` configuration property to override automatic configuration and use persistent data connection, for example `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:~/mydb` property will store your data into `~/mydb` file. Take a look at [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-sql) for more information on data source autoconfiguration and [HSQLDB documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html) for more information about HSQLDB configuration properties.